# invalid literal int base 10 occurring sporadically with the same variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Python3.4.2/tkinter program that requests a numeric user-entry which I have as a StringVar: my issue is that sometimes( probably about 30% of the time) it returns the invalid literal int base 10 and sometimes it functions perfectly. When the base 10 issue occurs I have to close the app and reopen.  Printing the StringVar always returns PY_VAR0 and from within the functions that use the StringVar, when the app functions, the number that was entered returns. When the base 10 issue occurs, the app 'crashes' returning only the PY_VAR0 and then the error message. If it were consistent I would understand where to hunt my error but with it behaving apparently irrationally I don't know how to start.
How do I go about investigating this issue?
The assignment part  this:

```
to_choose = StringVar()
#print(to_choose)
text = "\n{0}\n {1}".format("Enter number", "of Draws", pady = 10)
instruction = Label(actions_label_frame, text =text, bg = 'dark sea green', fg = 'dark slate gray')
instruction.grid(column = 2, row= 2, sticky = N)
how_many_draws_entry = Entry(actions_label_frame,  text = "", bd = 2, width = 3, bg = 'mint cream', fg = 'sea green', textvariable = to_choose, cursor = 'arrow', highlightcolor ='red')
```

The section that attempts to use the variable:

```
 mains_results = []

    draw = 0                                         # identifier for draw number to separate results clearly
    main_num_draws = int(to_choose.get())
    print("from main", main_num_draws)
    # check for empty string
    '''
    try:
        main_num_draws = int(to_choose.get())
    except ValueError:
        main_num_draws = 1
   '''
    while draw < main_num_draws:                  # loop 1 
        merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(final_list))   # flatten list
        # print(len(merged))                  #check length of list for pseudocheck
        random.shuffle(merged) 
        chosen = []                                 # accumulate eack pick in this list: reset here as well
        draw += 1                                   # increment draw identifier

        while len(chosen) <= 5:               # loop 2, to choose the five numbers of a draw
            pick = random.choice(merged)
            chosen.append(pick)
            merged = list(filter((pick).__ne__, merged)) # remove draw from choices(numbers)

            #print(len(merged)) #pseudocheck that values have been removed
        chosen.sort()

        mains_results.append(chosen)
```

and the error message:

```
    main_num_draws = int(to_choose.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Show us some code and the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. When you do this:

```
main_num_draws = int(to_choose.get())
```

... the error message is telling you that `to_choose.get()` is returning an empty string. An empty string is an invalid integer.

You need to either guarantee that the variable always has a valid integer in it, or you need to catch that error and handle it appropriately. Oddly, you have commented out code that does exactly that.

If you print one of these variables and see something like `PY_VAR0`, that just means you are doing something like `print the_variable` rather than `print the_variable.get()`. The string representation of the object isn't the value, it's a unique internal name (dumb design decision on the part of Tkinter designers IMO, but it is what it is).

Comment: Thank you for this. I have reinstated the routine to catch the error which seems to function. It puzzles me though why I get the problem in the first place. There is something that I have done with the Entry box or it is because I have to click on the IDLE shell to get the gui to respond which I am still trying to understand. I have run the gui in the terminal, but then I need to click in the terminal to get the gui to respond?